# How does CakePHP use the 'hash' field/column in User?

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I have a **CakePHP 2.3** app with a **MySQL** database.

I'm building a new app (in a different language and framework).

The plan is to completely replace the CakePHP app with the new one. The code is almost ready, so I've just attempted to run it in production for the first time.

User login seems to have crashed in production because the field `hash` in the `users` table was changed to `old_hash`. I did this because the new framework can't have fields with the name `hash`.

Testing in development, this was not a problem at all.

In production it became a problem.

**Development:**
App in Vagrant VM and database in my machine's local MySQL
(MySQL 5.7)

**Production:**
App in AWS EC2 and database in AWS RDS
(MySQL 5.6)

Because all `users` have the `hash` column **blank**, I assumed it didn't matter.
The fact that it worked locally after changing it to `old_hash` led me to worry even less about it.

I've searched for documentation on this specifically, but did not find anything detailed enough.

What does CakePHP use the `hash` field/column in the `users` table for?

Is there a place in the code where I can **explicitly** tell it to look for something named `old_hash` instead?

What could be influencing the difference in behaviors between development and production?

Figuring all of this out would be awesome, because then my 2 apps would be able to briefly coexist in production, making the transition smoother.

Comment: There is no code in the CakePHP core that refers to a the specific column named `hash`, so it's probably something specific to your application that you need to look up in your codebase. The only thing that comes close is the name `digest_hash` that is used in the [**digest auth example code**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords-for-digest-authentication) in the docs.

Comment: You say "User login seems to have crashed because..." What makes you think it's because of this? If there's an error pointing to this, share those details.

Comment: So the error kept saying that it didn't find the users.hash field. After trying so many times and so many different things, my brain needed a reset, so I undid everything and started over. It worked fine. I'm wondering now if maybe I'd just not cleared cache well enough, or at the right time, the first time. Thank you for helping anyways! ndm's answer is what got me thinking I should restart.